# Is a question about babyproofing on topic here?

Tags: discussion, scope

My toddler is into everything. I have a question about how to babyproof some of my stuff. Would it be on topic here?

Comment: Make sure you add age and country.  EG uk sockets do not need covers.

Answer (score 7):

Yes. It'd fall under [safety considerations](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) (and typically is tagged [safety](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/safety) although I wouldn't object if you create [child-proofing](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/child-proofing)).

Just make sure you're asking about general principles and not specific product recommendations.

Comment: Not a product recommendation, don't worry ;)